# Anonymous Record constructors in delphi

Tags: delphi, anonymous-types

Is it possible to use records as a method parameter, and call it without implicitly declaring an instance of said record?

I would like to be able to write code like this.

```
type
  TRRec = record
    ident : string;
    classtype : TClass;
  end;

procedure Foo(AClasses : array of TRRec);
```

then calling the method like this or something similar.

```
Foo([('Button1', TButton), ('Lable1', TLabel)]);
```

I'm still stuck on Delphi 5 by the way.

Comment: you mean without EXPLICITLY declaring an instance of said record, don't you? ;)

Comment: It might also be better to say "anonymous record _initialisers_"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. Almost.

```
type
  TRRec = record
    ident : string;
    classtype : TClass;
  end;

function r(i: string; c: TClass): TRRec;
begin
  result.ident     := i;
  result.classtype := c;
end;

procedure Foo(AClasses : array of TRRec);
begin
  ;
end;

// ...
Foo([r('Button1', TButton), r('Lable1', TLabel)]);
```

Comment: Note the unfortunate redundancy. You have to manage `TRRec` membership once in the type definition `type TRRec = record <foo1, foo2, ...>` and again as parameters in the defining declaration `function r(<foo1, foo2, ...>): TRRec`. [The alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614708/1054397) is less tedious to maintain.

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to work with a const array, but it isn't so flexible as the solution given by [@dan-gph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614622/1054397):
(especially that you have to give the size ([0..1]) of the array in the array declaration. The records are anomymous, the array isn't).

```
type
  TRRec = record
    ident : string;
    classtype : TClass;
  end;

procedure Foo(AClasses : array of TRRec);
begin
end;

const tt: array [0..1] of TRRec = ((ident:'Button1'; classtype:TButton),
                                   (ident:'Lable1'; classtype:TLabel));

Begin
  Foo(tt);
end.
```